# C# checkbox and mouse click event

Tags: c#, checkbox, mouseclick-event

I am self teaching myself C# and ran into a problem I haven't seem to find an answer too. I have a Form that when I mouse click the check box the state goes to true but also immediately triggers the mouse click event I have code follows:

```
private void uxCheckBoxMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs) e;
    if (uxMouseCopyCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
        uxMouseCopyCheckBox.Checked = false;

    }
}
```

I have searched the stack overflow and Google and found similar items but not in C# but no luck on the fixed solution. What I want to do it use the first click to change the check box to true without triggering the mouse click event. I want to delay the event to the 2nd mouse click and not the first.

I have tried the following:

- for loop
- Clicks == 2 with if statement
- subscribing but at a loss on what to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a boolean variable as a flag.

```
private bool wasAlreadyClickedOnce;

private void uxCheckBoxMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!wasAlreadyClickedOnce)
    {
        wasAlreadyClickedOnce = true;
        return;
    }

    if (uxMouseCopyCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
        uxMouseCopyCheckBox.Checked = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me out, but now I need to research why the mouse click in focused on the check box area only and not the entire form.

Comment: @Solorn I'd say this is because you selected the checkbox when you subsribed your Handler to the Click Event. If you want the Handler to be executed for a click on the whole form, you'll have to subscribe it to the Form's Click event

Comment: Yes I discovered that just shortly after I posted my comment =/ Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the `Click` event you could subsribe to the `CheckedChanged` event :

The Handler will look look exactly like yours :

```
private void uxMouseCopyCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!uxMouseCopyCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
        uxMouseCopyCheckBox.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

The only difference is that we want the Message box to be shwon only on the second click so when you will uncheck the checkbox.

Be careful though, if you change the default state of the checkbox, it will no longer work.

If you want a really robust solution Grant's one is IMHO the best, mine was just here to show you how to adapt your code for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`Click`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) event instead of `CheckedChanged` event to check or uncheck the `CheckBox` and then you can use the `MouseClick` event for other stuff.

Comment: @Sidewinder94 I think he is using `MouseClick` event, not `Click` event

Comment: I have tried moving the code to the Click event and the same thing happens. As soon as I check the box the click event immediately fires off.